# Coefficients of polynomial with at least $r$ non-zero roots.

Tags: abstract-algebra, matrices, polynomials, roots

You have a polynomial $f$ of degree up to $k$ over a finite field with $q$ elements where $k|q-1$. If polynomial $f$ has $r<k$ distinct non-zero roots, what we can say about the non-zero coefficients of $f$? for sure the degree of $f$ is $s$ where $r\leq s\leq k$. We may assume $r>k/2$. We know the number of non-zero roots but their values are unknown. Vieta’s formula does not help in our case.

This question comes from an interesting approach to count the number of  non-singular Toeplitz matrices. Let $T_n(x)$ be a Toeplitz polynomial associated to a Toeplitz matrix of order $n$.  The result in [this paper](https://sci-hub.wf/10.1016/0196-6774(80)90013-9) says  if there is a reminder with degree exactly $n-1$ in  the Euclidean reduction sequence for $(x^{2n-1},T_n(x))$, then $T_n$ is non-singular.

$T_n = \begin{bmatrix} a_{n-1} & a_{n} & a_{n+1} &\ldots & a_{2n-2}\\\\\ a_{n-2} & a_{n-1} & a_{n-2} &\ldots& a_{2n-3}\\\\\ a_{n-3} & a_{n-2} & a_{n-1} &\ldots& a_{2n-4}\\\\\ 
\vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \ddots & \vdots \\\\\ a_0 & a_1 & a_2 & \ldots & a_{n-1} \end{bmatrix}$

and $$T_n(x)=a_0+a_1x+a_2x^2+\ldots+a_{n-1}x^{n-1}+\ldots+a_{2n-2}x^{2n-2}$$

In our problem we have a Toeplitz polynomial $f$ which always has degree at least $n-1$.  Now we want to prove that there is always a reminder with degree $n-1$. When degree of $f$ is exactly $n-1$, it is trivial. We want to prove the case when $n-1<\mbox{degree}(f)\leq 2n-2$.